# Postgres geolocation: find a POI in radius

Tags: postgresql, geolocation, geocoding, geospatial, postgis

I have a Postgres DB table with the following schema:

```
POIUid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
POI_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Lat DOUBLE PRECISION,
Lon DOUBLE PRECISION
```

I would like to search for the nearest POI within a 5km radius.
I read that, for faster searches, I would need to use the Geospatial functions of PostgeSQL and create a new column in the table `COORDINATES` of a type POINT.

1. Should I just use `cube` and `earthdistance` extensions, or `postgis` extension?
2. How can I populate the new column with the data already in Lat/Lon fields?
3. I would presume I have to create an index on the new `COORDINATES` column, do the values have to be unique?

N.B. I have over 3 millions POI in the table already, with 10s of thousands duplicates on Lat/Lon.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you'll never use geospatial features other than lat/long distance, and a (somewhat inaccurate) perfectly spherical earth is acceptable for you then `earthdistance` should be enough. 2 & 3 depends on your choice, but in general: you don't *have to* create indexes, but it is highly advised, in order to speed up your select queries (but they *can* slow down your data-modifying queries -- this is their trade-off). And you don't *have to* make them unique neither. But if you really have completely duplicated rows, you should get rid of duplications anyway.